# WSO2 Failed Administrator login attempt 'admin[-1234]' at [2018-05-01 05:36:36,073+0000]

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I was originally using https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+the+Pre-Packaged+Identity+Server+5.2.0+with+API+Manager+2.0.0.

Now i migrated to API manager 2.1.0 and Id server 5.3.0
After migrating id server , I am unable to login. even for the admin/admin , I am unable to login.

The below error is shown

```
    [2018-05-01 05:36:53,528]  WARN {java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences} -  Couldn't flush system prefs: java.util.prefs.BackingStoreException: Couldn't get file lock.
[2018-05-01 05:36:36,073]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  Failed Administrator login attempt 'admin[-1234]' at [2018-05-01 05:36:36,073+0000]
```

I dont have any other errors in the log.But server takes long to start up because there is some messages like below

```
[2018-05-01 05:30:30,549]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} -  Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.common.IServerAdmin,
[2018-05-01 05:31:30,548]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} -  Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.common.IServerAdmin,
[2018-05-01 05:32:30,548]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} -  Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.common.IServerAdmin,


[2018-05-01 05:33:30,548]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} -  Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.common.IServerAdmin,

[2018-05-01 05:34:30,548]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} -  Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.common.IServerAdmin,
```

Any help plz

Comment: Above warning "Couldn't flush system prefs:" occurs due to lack of permissions. So please check whether the user who's running the WSO2 instance have writing permissions for /etc/.java/.systemprefs.

Answer (score 0):

can you check whether you have configured the user-mgt.xml in /repository/conf location please. check whether it is same in previous version and new version. Also check whether you configured the user store correctly in the repository/conf/datasources/master-datasources.xml file

Comment: My config looks correct.But i will double check..
I have mysql datasource..And since i cant allow any downtime for the upgrade , I created a snapshot of existing database and created a database from this snapshot and pointed to the new database. Hope this approach works fine.